# casting custom string to date in SQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, date, date-format

I have a column with strings such as `2015-W02`, meaning the second week of 2015. I would like to convert it to a date (e.g., corresponding to the Saturday of that week). It does not seem that CONVERT nor PARSE support this style. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Yes. All are YYYY-Wxx

Comment: PostgreSQL 10.14 (Ubuntu 10.14-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that week number identifies the [ISO week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering) (= week starts on Monday, first week belongs to the year where the "bigger" part falls into), you can use `to_date()`

```
select to_date('2015-W02', 'iyyy-"W"iw')
```

Note that this returns the Monday of that week, as this is how the ISO week is defined.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with dates I would suggest a calendar table, you can find some scripts to generate your own calendar tables on google.

In this case I've used a CTE to generate a series of dates for 2015 and below sample data:

> ```
> create table t (id int, dt text);
> insert into t values (1, '2015-W02'), (2, '2015-W08'), (3, '2015-W21');
> ```

```
with days as
(
    select dt, 
           extract(dow from dt) dow, 
           extract(week from dt) wk,
           extract(year from dt) yr
    from  generate_series('2015-01-01'::timestamp, 
                          '2015-12-31'::timestamp, 
                          '1 day'::interval) dt
)
select
  *
from 
  t
join
  days 
  on substring(t.dt, 1, 4)::int = days.yr
  and substring(t.dt, 7, 2)::int = days.wk
where
  days.dow = 6; --saturdays only
```

> ```
> id | dt       | dt                  | dow | wk | yr  
> -: | :------- | :------------------ | :-- | :- | :---
>  1 | 2015-W02 | 2015-01-10 00:00:00 | 6   | 2  | 2015
>  2 | 2015-W08 | 2015-02-21 00:00:00 | 6   | 8  | 2015
>  3 | 2015-W21 | 2015-05-23 00:00:00 | 6   | 21 | 2015
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c743439a79fc9acd1909fee53f1d0b76)*